Handling coordinate rotation in spherical coordinates with addition theorem
I'm working through a problem on the potential inside a hollow sphere of radius $a$ with a given boundary condition for the potential $\Phi$ on the surface,
$$
\Phi(r=a,\theta)=\begin{cases}V&\text{if }\theta\in[0,\pi/2)\\0&\text{if }\theta\in(\pi/2,\pi]\end{cases}
$$
The solution is a series of Legendre polynomials $P_\ell(\mu)$, where $\mu=\cos\theta$,
$$
\Phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty A_\ell r^\ell P_\ell(\mu)
$$
The coefficients $A_\ell$ are obtained by the orthogonality of Legendre polynomials.
$$
A_\ell=\frac V{2a^\ell}(2\ell+1)\int_{0}^1d{\mu} P_\ell(\mu)
$$
$$
A_0=\frac V2
$$
$$
A_{\ell\ge1}=-\frac{V}{2a^\ell}\frac{2\ell+1}{\ell}P_{\ell+1}(0)
$$
Evaluating $\Phi$ up to $\ell=1$, we get
$$
\Phi_{\ell\le1}(r,\theta)=\frac V2\left(1+\frac{3r}{2a}\cos\theta\right)
$$
We can solve the same problem with rotated coordinates, where the boundary condition now becomes
$$
\Phi'(r=a,\theta,\phi)=\begin{cases}V&\text{if }\phi\in[0,\pi)\\0&\text{if }\phi\in(\pi,2\pi]\end{cases}
$$
The solution involves spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)$.
$$
\Phi'(r,\theta,\phi)=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\alpha_{\ell,m}r^\ell Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)
$$
By the orthogonality of spherical harmonics,
$$
\alpha_{\ell,m}=\frac V{a^\ell}\int_0^\pi d{\phi}\int_{-1}^1 d{\mu}Y_{\ell,m}^*(\theta,\phi)
$$
Evaluating $\Phi'$ up to $\ell=1$,
$$
\Phi'_{\ell\le1}(r,\theta,\phi)=\frac V2\left(1+\frac{3r}{2a}\sin\theta\sin\phi\right)
$$
$\Phi_{\ell\le1}$ and $\Phi'_{\ell\le1}$ look similar, and it seems $\Phi'$ can be obtained alternatively by the addition theorem stated as,
$$
P_\ell(\cos\gamma)=\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\frac{4\pi}{2\ell+1}Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell,m}^*(\theta',\phi')
$$
where $\mathbf{r}(r,\theta,\phi)\cdot\mathbf{r}'(r',\theta',\phi')=rr'\cos\gamma$.
Here's the point where I'm confused. In my notes, it appears we evaluate
$$
\begin{split}
P_1(\cos\gamma)&=\sum_{m=-1}^1\frac{4\pi}{3}Y_{1,m}\left(\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)Y_{1,m}^*(\theta,\phi)\\
&=\frac{8\pi}{3}\Re\left\{Y_{1,1}\left(\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)Y_{1,1}^*(\theta,\phi)\right\}\\
&=\sin\theta\sin\phi
\end{split}
$$
While the result is clear to me, I'm uncertain why replacing $\cos\theta$ in $\Phi_{\ell\le1}$ with $P_1(\cos\gamma)=\sin\theta\sin\phi$ gives $\Phi'_{\ell\le1}$. What motivates this calculation, and how does it bridge the gap between $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$?
